# Transparent status bar, centred title, custom hamburger icon, and no background for appbarlayout

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar, toolbar

I am trying to make this ui for a project, but alas, i am stuck at throwing way too many hacks to get even close to this.

[image: Here's what I need to make]

Here's all that I have tried.

1. Window background is set to be the gradient, and then the bottom views have their own white background. Hate this because it's causing way too many draws
2. The spacing between the app bar and status becomes way too less if i use this:
       `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
           Window w = getWindow();
           w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
           w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
       }`
3. Adding a custom Textview and setting title to "", seems to help center the title, but the font is way off.
4. I have added the code `mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.hamburger);` for changing the drawer toggle icon, but it's not reflecting at all.
5. I had to manually set the `android:background="null"` for the appbarlayout to set it to become transparent. Could not find a way to use the theme for the same!

Any tips are very very welcome!

Comment: Have you achieved this layout?

Comment: Any success in this?